# modify output from HashMap and parse to Integer

Tags: java, parsing, io, hashmap

I cannot understand why the output in console is just adding another pair of elements to each line in my output. So there is the code:

```
package zadania;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Grades {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("oceny.txt"));
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] parts = line.split(":", 2);
            String key = parts[0];
            String value = parts[1];
            map.put("Student: " + key, "grade: " +value);
            System.out.print(map + "\n");
        }
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

And the output is like:

```
{Student: Kowalski Jan=ocena: 3}
{Student: Mak Ireneusz=ocena: 2, Student: Kowalski Jan=ocena: 3}
{Student: Mak Ireneusz=ocena: 2, Student: Gawron Tomasz=ocena: 5, Student:           Kowalski Jan=ocena: 3}
{Student: Szymczyk Jaroslaw=ocena: 4, Student: Mak Ireneusz=ocena: 2,  Student: Gawron Tomasz=ocena: 5, Student: Kowalski Jan=ocena: 3}
```

However, I just wanted output to be those pairs of keys and values one by one printed in a new line, but they are adding up each line.

Other thing is that my text file is like that:

```
Kowalski Jan:3
Mak Ireneusz:2
Gawron Tomasz:5
Szymczyk Jaroslaw:4
```

And my second question is: How do you parse the second column, which contains those grades to integer (like I want use  `TreeMap` )? 
I was reading it in various answers on StackOverflow, but I'm probably dumb to figure out how you parse it for map :D

Comment: You are invoking `System.out.print(map + "\n");` in each iteration. What do you think it does? BTW why `print(...\n)` instead of `println(...)`? Do you must use `\n` and not OS specific line separator?

Comment: Well I expected println (print is a mistake) to simply print out the map, not adding new pair of elements each line. I removed \n but it prints out almost the same way. Maybe i asked my question incorrectly. I need to print a one by one pair, not that they add up each line

Comment: It does simply print out the map, the thing is your are adding new elements to the map in each iteration. Answers have already shown you how to print only the most recent entry instead of the entire map.

Comment: Ok, sorted. What about the parsing the values for the map? Maybe anyone has an idea?

Comment: You can use Map.get() method to retrieve value by key, or use map.values() method to get all values at once. With iterator you can retrieve all key, value pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get this output is that each iteration of the loop prints your entire `map`. If you want to print only the last item added to the map, you can do it like this:

```
System.out.println(key + " : " + value);
```

Comment: Thank you. It's better now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
    System.out.print(map + "\n");
```

write

```
System.out.println("{Student: " + key+", grade: " +value+"}");
```